# app not showing in django admin site

Tags: python, django

i am trying to add app in django admin site, but the app is not showing, i have searched other questions for answer but they are almost 7 years old and it's all becoming very confusing, can someone help me please.

In settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
]
```

Following is the code in project's urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: App's will not show up in the admin section. You are thinking about `models` so the answers below will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you add

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mymodel.models import mymodel

admin.site.register(mymodel)
```

To

```
myapp/admin.py
```

Comment: It displayed error upon running the server    "no module named 'servers' "

Comment: Change mymodel to the name of the model in the "myapp"

Answer (score 0):

You should register your `myapp`'s models in `myapp/admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import MyModel


admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

Now it should appear when you visit `/admin`.

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'Mymodel'

Comment: @rushil Replace `MyModel` with your corresponding model from `myapp.models.py`

Answer (score 0):

Place this code inside your app's `admin.py` file. Replace `myapp` with your app name and `Author` with your model name.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Author

admin.site.register(Author)
```

It is documented at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects